# How to use $inc, $min and $setOnInsert in an update operation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to perform an operation like this in MongoDB:

Find the data through the query `{"name": "A.C. Abracus"}`. If the data doesn't exist, it will create the data in the database by using `$setOnInsert`. If the data exists, it will increase the cmtCount by 1, and in the meantime compares the new `point` value with the existing `point` in the database in order to choose the min one of them and update the `point` field with the min value.

The data in the MongoDB is like this below:

`>db.scores.find()`

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d08a9c83bb571704b774a60"), "name" : "A.C. Abracus", "assignment" : 5, "cmtcount" : 1, "point" : 33 }`

I have tried some operations like `findOneAndUpdate` and `update` with `$set, $setOnInsert, $inc, $min`, but doesn't work as my expectation. Like:

```
db.scores.update(
  {"name": "A.C. Abracus"},
  {
    $min: {"point": 10},
    $inc: {"cmtcount": 1},
    $setOnInsert: {"name": "A.C. Abracus", "assignment": 5, "point": 33}
  },
  {upsert: true}
)
```

I expect the result to be like this:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d08a9c83bb571704b774a60"), "name" : "A.C. Abracus", "assignment" : 5, "cmtcount" : 2, "point" : 10 }`

But this occured an error `"Updating the path 'point' would create a conflict at 'point'"`

I think maybe it is because when the data doesn't exist, it runs `$setOnInsert`, `$min` and `$inc` at the same time. So it occurs conflict.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!